# Azure Workload Identity - --enable-workload-identity via ARM template?

Tags: azure-aks, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I'm trying to create an ARM template to provision an Azure Kubernetes Service cluster with Azure workload identity pre-configure, similar to the result that the cmdlet below would produce:

`az aks create -g ${RESOURCE_GROUP} -n ${CLUSTER_NAME} --enable-oidc-issuer --enable-workload-identity`

I managed to enable OIDC issuer and workload identity in my ARM template:

```
       {
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "name": "[parameters('resourceName')]",
            "properties": {
               [...]
               "oidcIssuerProfile": {
                    "enabled": true
                },
                "workloadIdentity": {
                    "enabled": true
                },
                "securityProfile": {
                    "workloadIdentity": {
                        "enabled": true
                    }
                },
                [...],
            }
       }
```

But, after the script has executed, I can't see the `azure-wi-webhook-controller-manager` pods running under the `kube-system` namespace - It seems that the arm template does not install this component, that is required for Azure Workload Identity to work.

Is there a way I can install it through ARM?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your ARM template is the API version, workloadIdentity was not added until **2023-01-02-preview**. You're using 2019-06-01. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/change-log/managedclusters#2023-01-02-preview

For a reference, the [AKS Construction bicep](https://github.com/Azure/AKS-Construction/blob/21989e45744c09473a0efea980cc57e6cdb79b9a/bicep/main.bicep#L1301) implements workload identity and most other AKS features.

Comment: Oh nice shout, I'll give it a go!